# SWT browser issue

Tags: java, html, swt, browser-cache

I am using Eclipse SWT to embed a browser and load a webpage to the same.

The problem I am facing is that the site I load in SWT has API calls (Java API) in it, so when I load the site for the first time all APIs are being called and data is getting loaded in the embedded browser.

But after an update API the new (updated) data is not getting reflected in the embedded browser of SWT.

The workaround for the same is either I go to IE and open the page in which data is updated, after which the data is getting reflected in the SWT browser or I clear all the caches(website data) in IE.

Is there a way that the SWT loads data without doing the above workarounds?